# Code to add label to a MultiPage In user form

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have a code that creates a user form and also adds a Multipage to that user form what I then need is to add a Label Inside of that user form. As well as a Text box and a Button. Here is what I have.

```
Sub CreateUserForm()
Dim myForm As Object
Dim NewFrame As MSForms.Frame
Dim NewButton As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim NewButton1 As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim NewButton2 As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim NewButton3 As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim NewTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
Dim NewMultiPage As MSForms.MultiPage
'Dim NewTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
Dim NewLabel As MSForms.Label
'Dim NewOptionButton As MSForms.OptionButton
'Dim NewCheckBox As MSForms.CheckBox
Dim X As Integer
Dim Line As Integer

'This is to stop screen flashing while creating form
Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False

Set myForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)

'Create the User Form
With myForm
    .Properties("Caption") = "Job Template"
    .Properties("Width") = 500
    .Properties("Height") = 500
End With

'Create Multipage
Set NewMultiPage = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.MultiPage.1")
With NewMultiPage
    .name = "lst_1"
    .Top = 10
    .Left = 10
    .Width = 350
    .Height = 450
    .Font.Size = 8
    .Font.name = "Tahoma"
    .Pages.Remove ("Page2")



End With


'This is where i want the code to put stuff inside of the MultiPages.







'Create CommandButton in UserForm
Set NewButton = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
With NewButton
    .name = "cmd_1"
    .Caption = "Add Rev"
    .Accelerator = "M"
    .Top = 10
    .Left = 410
    .Width = 75
    .Height = 20
    .Font.Size = 8
    .Font.name = "Tahoma"
    .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
End With
'Create CommandButton in UserForm
Set NewButton1 = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
With NewButton1
    .name = "cmd_2"
    .Caption = "Remove Rev"
    .Accelerator = "M"
    .Top = 40
    .Left = 410
    .Width = 75
    .Height = 20
    .Font.Size = 8
    .Font.name = "Tahoma"
    .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
End With
'Create CommandButton in UserForm
Set NewButton2 = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
With NewButton2
    .name = "cmd_3"
    .Caption = "Enter Information"
    .Accelerator = "M"
    .Top = 70
    .Left = 410
    .Width = 75
    .Height = 20
    .Font.Size = 8
    .Font.name = "Tahoma"
    .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
End With
'Create CommandButton in UserForm
Set NewButton3 = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
With NewButton3
    .name = "cmd_4"
    .Caption = "Save"
    .Accelerator = "M"
    .Top = 100
    .Left = 410
    .Width = 75
    .Height = 20
    .Font.Size = 8
    .Font.name = "Tahoma"
    .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
End With
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Please be more specific when describing your exact problem - What outcome did you expect? What result did you get instead? Why do you suspect the error is happening, and what part of the code is likely responsible for causing the error?

Comment: Hello Nothing is wrong with my code everything works fine I can;t seem to find a way To add items to a MultiPage threw code I need to add a Text box and a label to the multipage that gets Created.

Comment: It's not helpful posting code where "everything works". Please narrow down the problem to the portion of the code you're working with to solve the specific problem at hand. I suggest rephrasing your question to make it clear what you're trying to add, where you're trying to add it to, and what errors are you getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'Create Multipage
Set NewMultiPage = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.MultiPage.1")
With NewMultiPage
    .Name = "lst_1"
    '...
End With

'put stuff inside of the MultiPages.
Set NewButton = NewMultiPage.Pages(0).Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
With NewButton
    .Name = "blah"
    '...
End With
```

Comment: Thank you Tim i will be able to modify this now this is just what I was looking for

Comment: I got another small question I use 'myForm.codemodule.insertlines 2,' to put code in the form module what would be code for Multipage so add code to

Comment: nvm its in the same module lines